# Get postcode and country_id from object mage 2

Tags: magento2

I get all data from checkout, with the next code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
            $shippingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            $perri = $shippingAddress->getData();
```

But i want to get only postcode and country_id from my object, if i use the next code, i can get the specific element:

```
$perri = $shippingAddress->getData('postcode');
```

If i use the next code,  the log show an error:

```
$perri = $shippingAddress->getData('postcode');
 $perri = $shippingAddress->getData('country_id');
```

How can i get both items?

Comment: Hi @Victor What kind of error it's giving?

Comment: Code is working, add more description of error.

Answer (score 0):

Magento recommends using `API interfaces` to fetch data.
You can use `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface` to get `postcode` and `country_id`
Using ObjectManager directly is not a good practice.

You can read more about API and interfaces at http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/

Answer (score 0):

Please try to fetch like below code using observe/plugin -

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    ) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getPostcode(){
   $this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
}
```

Let me know if this work for you.

Rashi